# x-api-key only secures some resources

Tags: amazon-web-services, flask, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway, zappa

My setup:

flask - awsLambda - zappa - api gateway

I do have a simple app running via above mentioned services.
In my zappa_settings.json I have 'api_key_required' set to true.

Is it possible to set it up the way, that I will be using api key for every resource endpoint, but one (swagger documentation).

If, yes, where actually do I have to set it up. I don't have any api key setup in my flask app, so I assume it has to be done somewhere in aws.console - but I cannot find it.

**EDIT**:
Just to add to correct answer (below). If you use [flasgger](https://github.com/rochacbruno/flasgger) it is not sufficient to add just one public endpoint pointing to **/apidocs**. To make documentation work without api key I had to open these enpoints:

1. **/apidocs** and **/apidocs/{proxy+}**
2. **/apispec_1.json** - may be different in your case
3. **/flasgger_static** and **/flasgger_static/{proxy+}**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, this is possible with a bit of configuration in the AWS console.

In your API Gateway setup you probably have the default resources created with a Zappa deployment: `/` and `/{proxy+}`.

[image: Default resources]

You can now manually create a new resource corresponding to your documentation endpoint (e.g. `/docs`).

Clicking on "Actions" -> "Create Resource" you can create the new resource:

[image: create new resource]

After the resource is created, click "Actions" -> "Create Method" and choose "ANY". Point the method and resource to your Lambda function in the dialog.

By default, the new resource should not require the API key.

[image: no api key required]

**Note:** you might need to redeploy the gateway before the changes take effect. "Actions" -> "Deploy API".